# In Android after Converting from ArrayList to String[] Array null values are populating in spinner

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner

i am populating the values dynamically from mysql database and adding the data to the Arraylist. Now if i want to populate the data in spinner it has to be converted into String [] array i have converted using

AidStr is a arraylist variable which contains values from the database.

```
Object[] ObjectList = AidStr.toArray();
  String[] StringArray = Arrays.copyOf(ObjectList,ObjectList.length,String[].class);
```

And

```
String[] stringArr = AidStr.toArray(new String[AidStr.size()]);
```

but it is not working i checked the size of the string array and it is showing as null in logcat as shown below

```
System.out.println("Lengtth of an array after convertion:"+stringArr.length);
  System.out.println("Lengtth of an array after convertion AIDSTR:"+AidStr.size());
```

Lengtth of an array after convertion: 0
Lengtth of an array after convertion AIDSTR: 0

when i check the arraylist values i am getting the correct output in logcat when i convert to string[] its stack is empty and length is equal to 0

```
 System.out.println("AID STRING ALL THE VALUES:"+AidStr);
```

Logcat output after printing the arraylist variable.

```
AID STRING ALL THE VALUES: [Apple, Ball, Bat]
```

Please help to convert the values to string[] and populate the correct data dynamically into spinner

```
MainActivity.java 

public class MainActivity extends Activity  {

final ArrayList<String> AidStr=new ArrayList<String>();
String php_send = null;
String name="fruits";
@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.mer_payment);
  System.out.println("AID STRING ALL THE VALUES ITEMS:"+items);
  new AsyncTaskOperation().execute(php_send);

  /*First method returning null values it is not working */
  Object[] ObjectList = AidStr.toArray();
  String[] StringArray = Arrays.copyOf(ObjectList,ObjectList.length,String[].class);

  /*One more method it is not working */
  String[] stringArr = AidStr.toArray(new String[AidStr.size()]);

  Spinner dropdown = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_tag);
  dropdown.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, StringArray);
  adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
  dropdown.setAdapter(adapter);

   Button buy_m = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buy_merchan);
  buy_m.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent buy_merchan = new Intent(this,PayActivity.class);
        buy_merchan.putExtra("title", name);
        startActivity(buy_merchan);
    }

  }); 
 }
public class AsyncTaskOperation extends AsyncTask <String, Void, Void>
    {
        @Override
         protected Void doInBackground(String... paramsObj) {
            php_send = "http://localhos/Android/App/mer.php";
            String str = "";
            HttpResponse response;
            HttpClient myClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost myConnection = new HttpPost(php_send);
            try {
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
                myConnection.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                response = myClient.execute(myConnection);
                str = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");      
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            String map; 
            try 
            {
                JSONArray data = new JSONArray(str);
                for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);
                    map = c.getString("variation");
                    AidStr.add(map); //add the values to the arraylist
                }   
            }catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("AID STRING ALL THE VALUES:"+AidStr);

        return null;
        }}}
```

how should i convert the Arraylist Aidstr to String[] Stringarray(assumption) variable such that i can link the varable into ArrayAdapter and populate the values

String array has to look like this

```
String[] items = { "Apple", "Ball", "Bat"}; instead now it is populating as shown above arraylist values
```

XML:

```
<Spinner
         android:id="@+id/spinner_tag"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
         style="@style/spinner_style"
         android:popupBackground="#D3D5D3"
         android:prompt="@string/select" />
```

This is xml file where spinner is implemented

Comment: at the time of conversion AidStr is empty ... AsyncTask.execute() is not blocking call it will **not** wait until doInBackground is finished ...

Comment: @Selvin can u tell me what i have to change in this code my friend please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are executing AsyncTask which run in background.
put this code in  side
**@Override
        protected void onPostExecute**

```
  Object[] ObjectList = AidStr.toArray();
  String[] StringArray = Arrays.copyOf(ObjectList,ObjectList.length,String[].class);

  /*One more method it is not working */
  String[] stringArr = AidStr.toArray(new String[AidStr.size()]);

  Spinner dropdown = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_tag);
  dropdown.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, StringArray);
  adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
  dropdown.setAdapter(adapter);
```